# Pandas/Python - determining local min and max of polynomial equation in a range

Tags: python, pandas, polynomial-math

I have a 4th order regression equation that I want to find the value of the dependent variable (y) and the corresponding independent variable (x) that gives it.  In essence, I am looking for the point where the curve slope is zero within a given range (the curve bottoms out).

The equation I have is:

```
y = 2661x^5 + 637x^4 + 9.32x^3 - 3.88x^2 - 0.62x + .21
```

and I am interested in the min y value in the range x[-0.155,0.103].

The actual equation variables are below:

```
     In [54]:

df3.dtypes
Out[54]:
date       datetime64[ns]
expDate    datetime64[ns]
X^5               float64
X^4               float64
X^3               float64
X^2               float64
X                 float64
Const             float64
minls             float64
maxls             float64
dtype: object

In [55]: 
df3

Out[55]:
        date    expDate          X^5         X^4       X^3       X^2  \
5 2008-01-02 2008-01-19  2661.368357  637.214501  9.320573 -3.884286   

          X    Const     minls     maxls  
5 -0.621015  0.21083 -0.154444  0.102655
```

where minls and maxls are the range variables

Is there an elegant way to do this?  I did look at scipy.optimize.brent but just couldn't follow the implementation of it.

I also wanted to mention that I have performed a group by [date, expDate] on the dataframe in case it matters to the solution.  My desire is to have a new variable df3.zerols contain the "ls" value within the range [minls,maxls]

Thanks in advance for any assistance

John

UPDATE:
I got some help, was abble to perform the needed process when I had just one row of data.  Below is the code that I have to date.  I need to be able to perform the same analysis on many rows after performing a group-by on date and expDate.

```
In [13]:


%cd C:\Users\camcompco\PycharmProjects\Regression
df=pd.read_csv('min.csv')
C:\Users\camcompco\PycharmProjects\Regression
In [14]:

df.head()
Out[14]:
       date    expDate      X^5     X^4    X^3   X^2     X  Const  minls  \
0  1/2/2008  1/19/2008  2661.37  637.21   9.32 -3.88 -0.62   0.21  -0.15   
1  1/2/2008  2/16/2008   188.65   94.25  11.00 -1.44 -0.73   0.22  -0.15   
2  1/2/2008  3/22/2008    28.31   19.98   3.85 -0.53 -0.57   0.23  -0.15   
3  1/3/2008  1/19/2008  2715.64  571.99  -6.31 -3.66 -0.48   0.20  -0.15   
4  1/3/2008  2/16/2008   135.61   76.55   9.96 -1.18 -0.70   0.21  -0.15   

    maxls  
0  0.1000  
1  0.1001  
2  0.1002  
3  0.1003  
4  0.1004  
In [21]:

row = df.iloc[0]
f = np.poly1d(row.iloc[2:8])
In [22]:

f
Out[22]:
poly1d([2661.3699999999999, 637.21000000000004, 9.3200000000000003,
       -3.8799999999999999, -0.62, 0.20999999999999999], dtype=object)
In [23]:

result = scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar(f, bounds=(row["minls"], row["maxls"]), method='bounded')
In [24]:

result.x
Out[24]:
0.066556628458908085
In [25]:

f(result.x)
Out[25]:
0.1702749792881138
In [ ]:
```

Comment: What resolution/precision do you need?

Comment: 4 decimals is the target (i rounded my numbers in the question for ease in typing)

Comment: You may find this ```scipy``` *leture* helpful, [2.7. Mathematical optimization: finding minima of functions](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/mathematical_optimization/#mathematical-optimization-finding-minima-of-functions).  It would be worthwhile to spend some time with it.

Comment: Are you looking for a local minimum or a point within a range with a slope of zero?

Comment: wwii, a local min value of y.  The updated question/answer had exactly what I need, I just need it to work for each row rather than the first row only (each unique date/expDate group).  Thanks much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say you want the place where the slope is zero, and then you say you want the minimum y value in a range.  Those two need not be the same (a local minimum need not even exist where you're looking).  Assuming that you're really interested in (a) minimum y value, we can use `np.poly1d` to turn your coefficients into a function, and then use `scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar` to find the minimum in your range.

First we make the polynomial:

```
>>> row = df3.iloc[0]
>>> f = np.poly1d(row.iloc[2:8])
>>> f
poly1d([2661.3683569999998, 637.21450100000004, 9.3205729999999996,
       -3.8842859999999999, -0.62101499999999998, 0.21082999999999999], dtype=object)
```

Always a good idea to check to make sure the coefficients are in the order we expect:

```
>>> f(0)
0.21082999999999999
```

And then we use `minimize_scalar` with the bounded method:

```
>>> result = scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar(f, bounds=(row["minls"], row["maxls"]), method='bounded')
>>> result
 message: 'Solution found.'
 success: True
     fun: 0.17101866540403174
  status: 0
       x: 0.06659055175137768
    nfev: 11
```

The value of `x` we want is in `result`:

```
>>> result.x
0.06659055175137768
>>> f(result.x)
0.17101866540403174
```

Comment: for some reason I am getting the following error : AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'endswith'.  the trace back points to  860         if name.endswith("*"):     any suggestions?

Comment: @John verify you are extracting the bounds and coefficients from the dataframe correctly.

Comment: thx wwii and DSM, I restarted my kernel and that error is gone . . .not sure what that was caused by . . .the issue I have is in having the process performed for each date/expDate combination for my data.  I have 1.7 million rows and over 7k unique date/expDate groups that each require their own result.  I don't how to post code in a "pretty" way, so sorry for the next line:        result = scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar(f, bounds=(row["minls"], row["maxls"]), method='bounded')
 then the next line is:           df2['result']=result.x

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar`, as demonstrated by @DSM, is **the best** solution - it has been optimized and for your example only takes 11 function evaluations ([`result['nfev']`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult.html#scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult)).  I was going there myself but I was too slow.

I'm going to offer a *roll-your-own* solution with *good enough* precision to give you an example of how to think about the problem - again, assuming you are looking for a local minimum not *a zero-slope*.

```
import numpy as np
```

Create a `poly1d`

```
f = np.poly1d([2661.3683569999998, 637.21450100000004, 9.3205729999999996,
       -3.8842859999999999, -0.62101499999999998, 0.21082999999999999])
```

Create an independent variable array with the required resolution (.01 for this example)

```
minx, maxx = (-0.154444,  0.102655)
#resolution = .0001
resolution = .01
x_s = np.linspace(minx, maxx, num = (maxx - minx)/resolution)

>>> x_s
array([-0.154444  , -0.14373154, -0.13301908, -0.12230663, -0.11159417,
       -0.10088171, -0.09016925, -0.07945679, -0.06874433, -0.05803188,
       -0.04731942, -0.03660696, -0.0258945 , -0.01518204, -0.00446958,
        0.00624287,  0.01695533,  0.02766779,  0.03838025,  0.04909271,
        0.05980517,  0.07051762,  0.08123008,  0.09194254,  0.102655  ])
>>> np.diff(x_s)
array([ 0.01071246,  0.01071246,  0.01071246,  0.01071246,  0.01071246,
        0.01071246,  0.01071246,  0.01071246,  0.01071246,  0.01071246,
        0.01071246,  0.01071246,  0.01071246,  0.01071246,  0.01071246,
        0.01071246,  0.01071246,  0.01071246,  0.01071246,  0.01071246,
        0.01071246,  0.01071246,  0.01071246,  0.01071246])
```

Create a dependent variable vector

```
v = f(x_s)

>>> v
array([ 0.30844319,  0.3008677 ,  0.29143552,  0.28137826,  0.27156949,
        0.26256978,  0.25467177,  0.2479452 ,  0.242282  ,  0.23744129,
        0.2330945 ,  0.22887038,  0.22440004,  0.21936206,  0.2135275 ,
        0.20680496,  0.19928564,  0.19128841,  0.18340481,  0.17654419,
        0.17197868,  0.17138828,  0.17690593,  0.19116253,  0.21733202])
```

Find the index of the minimum value of `v`

```
min_idx = np.where(v == v.min())

>>> min_idx
(array([21]),)
```

Use that index to retrieve the x value that *created* it.

```
local_min = x_s[min_idx]

>>> local_min
array([ 0.07051762])
```

[Boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) can get you there also

```
>>> x_s[v == v.min()]
array([ 0.07051762])
>>>
```